# edited files at host, but docker container is not refreshed

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to docker, I have successfully installed docker on ubuntu,
I am testing a node app, at folder: `/home/samir/Documents/docker-centos:`

```
$ ls                                                                                        
Dockerfile  Dockerfile~  index.js  index.js~  package.json  package.json~
```

I don't know what are those duplicates ending with `~` as I didn't add them.

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');

// Constants
var PORT = 8080;

// App
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // even if I change the output here, I still get Hello world only
  res.send('Hello world, This was added\n');
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Running on http://localhost:' + PORT);
```

Although I have started the container using a data volume that points to the same app dir like this:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -v /home/samir/Documents/docker-centos -d samir/centos-node-hello
```

but when I view the output like:

```
curl -i localhost:49160
```

I get `Hello world` even if I changed the file..

Do I miss something?
How would I run the container, and edit files at host? why it didn't work?

**EDIT**

Dockerfile

```
FROM    centos:centos6

# Enable Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) for CentOS
RUN     yum install -y epel-release
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN     yum install -y nodejs npm

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /src/package.json
RUN cd /src; npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /src

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["node", "/src/index.js"]
```

Comment: Did you restart the container?
docker restart conatiner-id . 
And can you add your Dockerfile here?

Comment: yes, I tried to to do restart, but I still see the same text output, kindly check the dockerfile above

Comment: Are you building the docker image again or not? You need to build the image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the Docker image again using the docker build command

Comment: Is this the only way to use docker? building the image again, will stop the nodejs server, and I will have to run it again and to some inits,, well?

Comment: I am not very good at Docker, but as far as my knowledge is concerned, you need to build the image again.
In development environment, you probably won't be building images again and again to test the changes.
As far as production is concerned, we have frameworks like Mesos and Marathon for managing the docker containers.

Comment: I am using Docker for development, did you use it in development without have to build the image again? is there a mode for development and another for production?

Comment: There is no development or production mode in Docker. I was just saying that you can build the node app directly without creating containers, and once its completed, only then build the docker image.
But as far as I know, you always need to build image for the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using this setup not only for one-off testing of your app, but for development as well, you'd be better off mounting your application code as a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/).